# Unexpected behavior of __DIR__ (evaluates to "xdebug:")

Tags: php

I've been working on a PHP project using Visual Studio and PHP Tools.

All of a sudden, out of nowhere, it started to evaluate the constant `__DIR__` as "xdebug:", which broke my `require` statements.

I removed `__DIR__` and hard coded the paths for the PHP files. Now it halts on the first line, that states simply

```
<?php
require "SomeDependency.php";
```

And says:

> Constant expression contains invalid operations

Comment: cam we see how you're using __DIR__ please?

Comment: I *was* using like this: `require __DIR__."\SomeDependency.php"` or `require __DIR__."\subdir\SomeOtherDependency.php"` but, as I said, I removed it and hardcoded the paths. And it keeps pestering me with that "Constant expression contains invalid operations", which doesn't make any sense...

Comment: are you declaring a static variable with another variable ?

Comment: @VBobCat yee I wouldn't use __DIR__ like that at all ... and it's possibly in your required file that gets the error ^^

Comment: what inside someDependency.php ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI, a class that contains only static methods.

Comment: show it please can you show it please ?

Comment: sorry, i ask if that work if you hard code the path instead of the __DIR__ ?

Answer (score -1):

Guys (@treyBake and @MohammedYassineCHABLI) , you are the best. I found that a newly added method inside the dependency file was causing the error:

```
public static function Main_Usuario_getUsuario_setor(int $setor_id, string $afastamentoInicio=date("Ymd His"), string $afastamentoFinal=date("Ymd His",time()+(5*24*60*60))) {...}
```

My bad, of course, but xdebug halting at the require line and changing the content of `__DIR__` constant and sending a cryptic exception message misguided me completely.